# React Render a parent only when Child is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if there is a way to only render a parent component when its child is rendered and vis versa. If you google the title you find quite a few entries but nothing the would work for my case because my elements aren't `undefined` or `null`, for example. Imagine a Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The following child might be depended on some settings. For instance, only show if a boolean is true.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const showChild = Settings.get(...);
        this.state = {
           visible:showChild
        }
      }

      render() {
        const showHello = this.state.visible ? <div>Hello</div> : "";
        return (
          <div>{showHello}</div>
        );
      }
    }
```

In my layout I scaffold it like this:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to unmount `Parent` if that `Child` element is not rendered? Thank you.

Update: A use case is if I want this `Parent` and `Child` to be in a `Layout` and `Parent` has a container class with a larger padding or margin because it is still in the component tree. If Child isn't rendered a large gap remains within the Layout and it just looks odd.

Comment: whats the use case for this? why do you want this?

Comment: I agree, more detail would be helpful here. Sounds like a classic XY problem right now.

Comment: @JordanHendrix I just added an update.

Answer (score 4):

React was not designed with this workflow in mind, in fact the opposite: data is explicitly passed down the DOM tree, while actions are passed upward. By extension, React must render your `Parent` before your `Child`.

I'd suggest refactoring your `Parent` and `Child` to the point where `Parent` is aware of which settings its `Child` needs; insofar as your `Child` component is engaged with:

```
<Child settings={settings} />
```

To reiterate, this is also a more natural approach to React, whereby data is explicitly passed downward, and not implicitly loaded in the `Child` (although there's always exceptions, like the ability of `connect()` components with `react-redux`). But a benefit to this approach is that now `Parent` is able to determine whether or not to render its `Child`.

But what about the rendering of `Parent`? Don't we want to inhibit that too? If you do, then you'll need your `Layout` component to be aware of what it's `Parent` component needs, therefore:

```
<Parent settings={settings} />
```

This is a common approach to `React` since rendering down the DOM hierarchy is a must.

Comment: That is a good approach. I would like to use the Parent component for more than one use case (for more than one Child component). Just wondering, I will have to have a very general approach for settings which in my opinion is not useful. Would that work? Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: @MichelH At the very least, your `Parent` component will need to be passed some type of `key` that you then use to call some `SettingsService.getSettingsByComponentType(type)`, now you have your settings in `Parent`, which now makes the component dynamic; you also have your metadata for `Child` and can render as you see fit. I've used this approach recently, and it's having some pretty good benefits. Take a look at line 43, then 60 (https://github.com/mikechabot/yet-another-app/blob/master/src/components/form/form-field.js)

Comment: In React, we can go as far as actually storing the component itself on other objects, or even retrieve it from a service. So really any approach is valid.

Comment: I can't access your repository. Is it privat?

Comment: Shoot, sorry - here's a public gist of it: https://gist.github.com/mikechabot/f0a9350250d93b5cd882580fa9874dc6

Answer (score -2):

You could conditionally render in your `Parent` component by checking to see if it has any children.

Use `this.props.children.length` to see if there are any, if yes, render normally, if not return an empty element.